# Changing EditText's icon color on focus

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

In the material design guidelines we can find the following:
[image]
An EditText with an icon that changes color on focus.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour with the built-in design support library 24.2.0? Is there a seamless attribute to get it done, something like the `app:passwordToggle` attributes ?

Note that using EditText's `drawableStart` or `drawableLeft` attribute will make the icon appear on the bottom line of the EditText

[image]

and not outside of it as showcased on the material design guildelines (cf:First Picture)

Answer (score 6):

Have two icons grey and blue handy and replace the drawables in selector with appropriate names.

Create a selector `phone_drawable_selector.xml` as below:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item 
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/phone_grey" 
        /> <!-- not focused -->
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/phone_blue" 
        /> <!-- focused -->    
</selector>
```

Use `drawableStart` or `drawableLeft` attribute of `EditText` as:

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone_drawable_selector.xml"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle and update UI in Android widget is use of drawable file in in background instade of directly using image.

In drawable xml file Android have a TAG of selector in which we can get widget different status like,pressed,focused and default.

For your reference review the below code for XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_pressed" </item> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/edittext_focused_blue" </item> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/edittext_normal" </item> <!-- default --> </selector>
```

Use drawableStart or drawableLeft attribute of EditText as:

```
<EditText ... android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone_drawable_selector.xml" ...

</EditText>
```